# Straight and simple answer: installing py2app

Tags: python, installation, py2app

I have been searching all day how to install py2app. I have downloaded the folder but I don't know how to actually install the application.
Also, if anyone could give me an easy way of using py2app that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Which Python version are you using?
Assuming you use Mac OS X version, first you need to install pip. 
For that google: how to install python pip?
This is really easy.
And after that issue in your terminal

```
  $ sudo pip install -U py2app
```

Answer (score 0):

if you already have the source package downloaded, it has a `setup.py` file in it's top-level directory.  To install, just invoke it like this:

`python setup.py install`

also, you could read the installation instructions:
https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/install.html